# reverse (left) arrow in an algorithm?

Tags: algorithm

There is a algorithm, in which author has written steps of algorithm like this,

1. Initialization: Set up the threshold (th) and maximum iteration number, I.

   i ← 0
2. Calculate x

   While (x > th) do

   i ← i+1

   ...

   End While

What does this left arrow means here?

Comment: Left arrow means assignment.

Comment: latex is not working here?or if i am typing it wrong?

Comment: [so] doesn't support LaTeX, so you'd need to figure something else out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The left arrow statement here that the value `i+1` is stored in the variable `i`.

That is, `i` is incremented by 1.

Answer (score 2):

Left arrow (as well as right one) means *assignment*, in your case an *equivalent C# code* is

```
  i = 0;

  while (x > th) {
    i = i + 1;
    ...
  }
```

Comment: I had thought right arrow usage was generally 'if ... then' or 'A right-arrow B' could indicate a mapping from A to B.